# Solr Spellcheck request returns nothing

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I actually use Solr 4.8.1 and I set up spellcheck. After indexing, the request doesn't return any suggestion.

After the advice of @n0tting, I modified a little my files.

Here are steps:

## 1- solrconfig.xml

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">phraseText</str>

    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">title_spellcheck</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

add some configurations in standard requestHandler:

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true">
    <!-- default values for query parameters -->
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>

      <!-- Optional, must match spell checker's name as defined above, defaults to "default" -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <!-- omp = Only More Popular -->
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
      <!-- exr = Extended Results -->
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
      <!--  The number of suggestions to return -->
      <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
    </lst>

    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>      
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

## 2 schema.xml

Define a field for spell check:

```
  <field name="title_spellcheck" type="phraseText" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

  <copyField source="title" dest="title_spellcheck"/>
```

## 3 Request:

```
  .../select?q=recommend&defType=edismax&qf=title&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true&spellcheck.q=recommend&spellcheck.collate=true
```

I don't get any suggestion at result, neither `<lst name="spellcheck">`. can anybody give me an advice? Thanks a lot.

References:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spell+Checking

http://solr.pl/en/2011/05/23/%E2%80%9Ccar-sale-application%E2%80%9D-%E2%80%93-spellcheckcomponent-%E2%80%93-did-you-really-mean-that-part-5/

Comment: According to the spellcheck definition in 1), the type of the field `title_spellcheck` should be `phraseText` instead of `text` in 2). Also, `title_spellcheck` is mispelled (`titre_spellcheck`) in the spellchecker definition in 1). The rest looks fine to me.

Comment: @n0tting: thank you for your answer. I modified the type to phraseText and the name to title_spellcheck. But there isn't suggestion.

Comment: Can you update your answer to reflect the changes? Try to declare explicitly the spellcheck dictionary: in solrconfig.xml spellcheck definition, add this line: `<str name="name">default</str>`. Does your search quey give you results ?

Comment: @n0tting: I updated my question with corrections in the configuration files. The search query returns 0 result: `<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>`

Comment: is `phraseText` defined as a field type in schema.xml (if not, use `textSpell`)? 
Are you querying the desired Request Handler (since your request path uses "/select", be sure that no request handler has that name, and that `handleSelect="true"` is specified in the requestDispatcher)?

Comment: @n0tting: Thank you very much! As I use the request handler /select, I shoud put `<arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>      
    </arr>` in `<requestHandler name="/select" ...>`, but not in the "standard" request handler. Now search queries return suggestions.